# How to post on Timeline in LINE in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, line.app

I want to open NAVER's `LINE.app` from within my iOS app using a URL scheme, and let my user share my iOS app using the preset string and AppStore URL.

I already set `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, and I know how to share a string to friends (using `line://msg/text`).

But how can I let him post it to the timeline? I even can't get to the documentation page but they clearly said it is feasible [in the docs](https://developers.line.me/line-it/line-it-button-for-websites).

> User selects who to share the content with. (Content can be shared with friends or posted on the user’s Timeline).

NOTE: I don't want to share it via Activity Controller. I want to use `UIButton` to trigger the share action.